# Django Save data inputted inn one model instance to another model

Tags: python, django

I have a model call Teacher that teaches classes which has ' rating' attribute. After each class each student in his class can comment and review his performance. They do so by creating a new object instance of OccurrenceRating. How do I make each new 'rating' from the OccurrenceRating instance save to the teacher instance 'rating' and make sure the average is correct. I've been able to display the average amount for each teacher by getting all the OcccurrenceRating objects with that teacher and the get the average for that but I've not been able to save that value. How do I do this?

**Models.py**

*Teacher Model*

```
class ProfileTeacher(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Creation Date')
    user = models.OneToOneField(app_settings.USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Surname')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Phone Number')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'City')
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Postal Code')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Address')
    nationality = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)', null=True, blank = True)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'ID Number(NIF/NIE)')
    bank_account = IBANField(verbose_name='IBAN', blank = True, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank = True, null = True, verbose_name='Date of birth')
    #To enable them showing up in search. Only active teachers are shown and preapproved needs to be true to be active
    preapproved = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Pre-Approved')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Active')
    #Braintree and Milingual Terms of Service Acceptance
    tos = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    #If true will receive classes email notifications
    email_notification = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name="Recibir Notificaciones")
    GENDER = (
       ('male','Male'),
       ('female','Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, blank = True, null=True, verbose_name = 'Gender' )
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, null = True, blank=True)
    teacher_type = models.ForeignKey(TeacherType, null = True, blank=True, verbose_name='Type')
    cvv = models.FileField(upload_to=teacher_cv_directory_path, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name="CV")
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=teacher_avatar_directory_path,
                                      null = True,
                                      blank=True,
                                      default='/perfil.png',
                                      )


    RATINGS = (
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    rating = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2,default=0, choices=RATINGS, blank=True, verbose_name="RATINGS", null=False)
    #True if the profile will appear on milingual site as Public
    published = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank=False, default=True)
    #Url: Teacher's Url
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name='Url')
    # True if teacher is legacy
    legacy = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    legacy_id = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Teachers'
        verbose_name = 'Teacher'

    @property
    def absolute_rating(self):
        return int(float(self.rating)/5 * 100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Check how the current values differ from ._loaded_values. For example,
        # prevent changing the creator_id of the model. (This example doesn't
        # support cases where 'creator_id' is deferred).
        #Building_unique_url
        url =  str(self.first_name).lower() + '_' + str(self.last_name).lower() + '_' + str(int(self.user.id))
        self.url = url
        if self.rating == '':
            self.rating = 0

        if self.profile_image!='/perfil.png'and self.cvv!='':
            self.preapproved = True
        else: 
            self.preapproved = False

        try:
            this = ProfileTeacher.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if this.profile_image != self.profile_image:
                this.profile_image.delete(save=False)
        except: pass # when new photo then we do nothing, normal case

        super(ProfileTeacher, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

*Class OccurrenceRating Model*

```
class OccurrenceRating(models.Model):
    # Update
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Updated')
    # Created
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Creation Date')
    # Author
    student = models.ForeignKey(ProfileStudent, verbose_name = 'Student')
    # Rating Value: 1 - 5
    CHOICHES =(
        (1, '1'),
        (2, '2'),
        (3, '3'),
        (4, '4'),
        (5, '5'),
    )
    occurrence = models.ForeignKey(Occurrence, verbose_name = 'Class')
    # Teacher Rating
    tc_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICHES, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Evaluación Profesor')
    # Feedback to teacher
    tc_comment = models.TextField(max_length = 5000, null=True, blank = False, verbose_name = 'Comentario al profesor')
    # Feedback to teacher
    vn_rating = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICHES, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Evaluación Local')
    # Occurrence comment
    vn_comment = models.TextField(max_length = 5000, null=True, blank = False, verbose_name = 'Comentario al Local')
    # Occurrence Rated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the `Teacher` instance rating on any new instance of that teacher's rating by a student.

**Example**:

```
# req_query_teacher_id - I am assuming it is from the query params in request
teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=req_query_teacher_id)

oc = OccurrenceRating.objects.create(...)

# get average rating for this teacher
avg_rating = get_avg_rating(teacher)
teacher.rating = avg_rating
teacher.save()
```

Whenever a new student rating instance is created, update the teacher's average rating considering all the rating that exist at that moment.